# Properties not updated on WPF control initialization

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, initialization, dependency-properties

I'm new to WPF, and am having trouble getting the values for properties for a custom user control from the MainWindow XAML file.

Here, I want to get the value "8" as the number of rows and columns but in my InitializeGrid() method, the properties are never set. They are always "0". What am I doing wrong?

Any references will also be appreciated.

---

This is my MainWindow.xaml (the relevant portions):

```
<local:BoardView 
    BoardRows="8" 
    BoardColumns="8"
    />
```

This is my BoardView.xaml:

```
<UniformGrid 
        Name="uniformGrid" 
        Rows="{Binding BoardRows}"
        Columns="{Binding BoardColumns}"
        >

    </UniformGrid>
</UserControl>
```

And this is my BoardView.xaml.cs:

```
[Description("The number of rows for the board."),
 Category("Common Properties")]
public int BoardRows
{
    get { return (int)base.GetValue(BoardRowsProperty); }
    set { base.SetValue(BoardRowsProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty BoardRowsProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("BoardRows", typeof(int), typeof(UniformGrid));

[Description("The number of columns for the board."),
 Category("Common Properties")]
public int BoardColumns
{
    get { return (int)base.GetValue(BoardColumnsProperty); }
    set { base.SetValue(BoardColumnsProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty BoardColumnsProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("BoardColumns", typeof(int), typeof(UniformGrid));

public BoardView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
    InitializeGrid();
}

private void InitializeGrid()
{
    int rows = BoardRows;
    int cols = BoardColumns;

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            uniformGrid.Children.Add( ... );
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this binding set up:

```
<UserControl ...>
    <UniformGrid 
        Name="uniformGrid" 
        Rows="{Binding BoardRows}"
        Columns="{Binding BoardColumns}"
        >

    </UniformGrid>
</UserControl>
```

The problem is that your binding is not working because the binding uses the default data source which is the `DataContext` of the `UserControl`.  You probably haven't set the `DataContext` but that's OK because that's not what you want anyway.

You want to bind the number of `Rows` in the `UniformGrid` to the `BoardView.BoardRows` property.  Since the `UserControl` is the previous code snippet **is** a `BoardView`, you can give the `BoardView` a name and use the `ElementName` syntax to refer to it like this:

```
<UserControl Name="boardView" ...>
    <UniformGrid 
        Name="uniformGrid" 
        Rows="{Binding BoardRows, ElementName=boardView}"
        Columns="{Binding BoardColumns, ElementName=boardView}"
        >

    </UniformGrid>
</UserControl>
```

This says: "Bind `UniformGrid.Row` to the `BoardRows` property of the element named `boardView`", just what you want!

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the property update. I also had to move the call to InitializeGrid() to uniformGrid_Loaded; can't have it in the constructor. Thanks :)